# Why are the exemptions for travelling from Ukraine to Crimea so narrow?

Tags: ukraine, crimea

Courtesy of [this answer on Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/67970/324), most foreigners aren't allowed to cross from mainland Ukraine into Crimea, with a few narrow exemptions, at least as of 2015. [Procedure for entry to the temporarily occupied territory of Ukraine and exit from it](http://finland.mfa.gov.ua/en/press-center/notices/4431-procedure-for-entry-to-the-temporarily-occupied-territory-of-ukraine-and-exit-from-it) mentions diplomatic and consular functions, journalist activities, and religious activities. So someone couldn't go to Crimea just to experience Crimean Tatar culture as a tourist, or learn the Crimean Tatar language, as far as I can tell.

Why are the exemptions for travel so narrow? What's the rationale?

Comment: To make it difficult to visit a place under foreign occupation? Seems a reason good enough to me.

Comment: Considering Crimea is a geopolitically volatile place that is a big target for spies and rebels, its probably in Russia's best interests to keep Crimea on lockdown.

Comment: Experiencing Crimean Tatar culture under the Russian okkupation is nowadays [difficult](http://www.freerepublic.com/focus/news/3216866/posts) *even for the Crimean Tatars*, leave alone the foreigners. It's like trying to visit **Oświęcim/Auschwitz** region of Poland in 1940 to learn the Polish Jews' culture.

Comment: @David the ban is imposed by Ukraine, not Russia.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Same idea though. Ukraine has had a lot of rebellion issues in the east, and it all started with Crimea. Ukraine wants to lock it down before it gets worse.

Comment: @bytebuster "come on Bytebuster, while Stalin's actions in 1944 can rightfully be called a genocide, comparing modern day Russia with nazi Germany is [clicks link] ... oh." To be pedantic, that was destroying Ukrainian culture, not Crimean Tatar culture.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm and now it's 2022 and Vlad wants to exterminate all Ukrainians.